# NameError: undefined local variable or method on scan method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error on`scan` method with `regex`

```
#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `　' for #<MacShop:0x007faa2b059998>>
```

When I invoke the rake task for the parsing it will give me that error.

However, When I tried to replay the bug, it disappear in the pry/rails console.

That is the bug only happens when I execute the rake task, How could I get rid of it?

The exception happened at line 59

```
        57: def get_modifier(line)
        58:   begin
        59:     matchers = line.scan(/(\[.*?\])/).first[0].split("/")
        60:   rescue Exception => e
        61:     ap(e)
        62:     binding.pry
     => 63:     matchers = [""]
        64:   end
        65:   matchers
        66: end

    [1] pry(#<MacShop>)> e
    => #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `　' for #<MacShop:0x007faa2b059998>>
    [3] pry(#<MacShop>)> play -l 59
    => ["[賣", "台南]"]
```

GEMFILE

```
gem "hirb-unicode"
gem "bond"
```

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue? Maybe some non-ascii character in this file, which Ruby would then interpret as the name of a variable?

Comment: You should ideally never rescue from Exception but from StandardError.

Comment: Can you also show the `line` variable when the error occurs?

Comment: And the best would be if you provided the complete stack trace (first few lines should be sufficient). BTW, the character in the exception is the [U+3000 character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) - "ideographic space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use "//" instead of "/"

"/" mean is ' "
But "//" mean is "/"

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the exception by removing the `begin rescue Exception => e` block,
But still not knowing the reason.
My ruby version is 2.2.2